# Disqus comment count in TYPO3 tt_news

Tags: typo3, disqus, tt-news

Is there a possibility to create in TYPO3 tt_news list/latest view link to article with `#disqus_thread` at the end of link i.e.:

`<a href="http://example.com/article/article_title.html#disqus_thread">Number of commments</a>`?

Anyone ever tried to view the comments count in tt_news extension?

Thanks for any help!

Regards,
Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `tt_news'` manual for section **Extending tt_news**, most probably you can just use `itemMarkerArrayFunc` fpr creating custom tags, there are some samples in `typo3conf/ext/tt_news/res/` folder.

Using it you can just handle some new marker like: `###LINK_TO_DISQUS###`

Note, I don't know the Disqus' API, anyway most probably id doesn't require much effort.

Comment: Thank's Biesior - I will try with that :)